# This tensor equation in Gerard t' Hooft's notes on General Relativity

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation

This question probably has a simple answer that I'm just missing, but in Gerard 't Hooft's lectures on GR he has the following:

$$X^{\mu}=Y_{\mu\alpha}Z^{\alpha\beta\beta}.$$

Why is the result of this a (1,0)-tensor? Do the $\alpha$'s not contract and the $\beta$'s also, leaving the $\mu$ index down? [Source, Equation 1.15, Page 6.](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/genrel_2010.pdf)

Comment: The indices aren't consistent, unless the metric is fully euclidian with cartesian coordinates only.

Comment: It must be a typo.

Comment: The notes seem to use a Euclidean metric and sum over indices both lowered as in 1.7 or both upper as in 1.15. This result is a (1,0) tensor because $X^{\mu}$ has one upper index, and it's likely a typo that $Y$ has the $\mu$ down, or he lowered it with the Kronecker delta just to force you to think, so really it's $\delta^{\mu \sigma} Y_{\sigma \alpha} = Y_{\mu \alpha}$

Comment: He mentions using somewhat non-standard index notation in this section on special relativity. This must be what he meant, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going crazy, thanks.

Comment: Sorry but this pdf text is really a piece of garbage.  It's full of index non-senses, weird notations, and is a good (?) example of what NOT to do in any pedagogical text, even if it comes from a well known physicist (and especially in the case of a well known physicist, anyway) !

Comment: See for example equation (7.33) on page 35.  Or (8.28) on page 39.  There are many like this one, in a General Relativity text!?  Come on!

Comment: The notes look pretty bad, but the Schwarzschild derivation looks good (his string notes don't have any of these oddities).

Comment: Maybe he was proof reading it using a holograph.